# How to stop/disable Bitnami Stack WP instances in Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I was wondering if anyone here knows how to stop/disable a WP instance in an azure VM. I know that even if these WP instances are inactive, they can still affect other WP instances in the same VM as they still run as background process